# How to render phantomjs pdf to a stream that can be returned?

Tags: javascript, phantomjs

I'm using the `phantomjs` `rasterize.js` to render a webpage to `pdf`.

```
var page = require('webpage').create()
...
page.render(output);
```

Problem: here the page is always saved to local file system. But I want to return the pdf stream from the javascript, and then offer it by an additional servlet. So no local files are written.

Is that possible, on windows?

Comment: Solution: http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/method/render-base64.html

Comment: No, I cannot render the webpage to an image. Is must be pdf, so I cannot use base64 hrtr.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't notice that pdf is not in supported formats

Answer (score 2):

Found it: `page.render('/dev/stdout', { format: 'pdf' });`

This can be read eg by java with:
`InputStream is = process.getInputStream();`